# Unable to convert a canvas type image code to SVG.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

I have coded a canvas image, the below code is capable of packing the blocks into a given panel of various sizes. I want to implement the same using the SVG

I have tried with SVG.js. I have no idea about the SVG. Any pointers would be great.

The motive behind using the SVG is to scale the image to any resolution. I was actually looking for a smaller canvas image, however if i change the resolution of canvas that would diminish the quality of image.

SVG.js
The lightweight library for manipulating and animating SVG.

Why choose SVG.js?
SVG.js has no dependencies and aims to be as small as possible while providing close to complete coverage of the SVG spec. If you're not convinced yet, here are a few highlights.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#canvas { background-color: #FBFBFB; }
#unsupported               { border: 1px solid red; background-color: #FFFFAD; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; }
textarea { resize: none; }
select   { width: 8em;   }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="packing">
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div id="desc"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.7.1/svg.min.js"></script>

<script src='js/demo.js'>          </script>

<script>
Packer = function(w, h) {
 this.init(w, h);
};
Packer.prototype = {
 init: function(w, h) {
  this.root = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   w: w,
   h: h
  };
 },
 fit: function(blocks) {
  var n, node, block;
  for (n = 0; n < blocks.length; n++) {
   block = blocks[n];
   if (node = this.findNode(this.root, block.w, block.h))
    block.fit = this.splitNode(node, block.w, block.h);
  }
 },
 findNode: function(root, w, h) {
  if (root.used)
   return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
  else if ((w <= root.w) && (h <= root.h))
   return root;
  else
   return null;
 },
 splitNode: function(node, w, h) {
  node.used = true;
  node.down = {
   x: node.x,
   y: node.y + h,
   w: node.w,
   h: node.h - h
  };
  node.right = {
   x: node.x + w,
   y: node.y,
   w: node.w - w,
   h: h
  };
  return node;
 }
}

function sortAllBlocks(blocks, type) {
    var func;
    switch (type) {
        case 'random':
            func = function(a, b) {
                return Math.random() - 0.5;
            };
            break;
        case 'w':
            func = function(a, b) {
                return b.w - a.w;
            };
            break;
        case 'h':
            func = function(a, b) {
                return b.h - a.h;
            };
            break;
        case 'a':
            func = function(a, b) {
                return b.w * b.h - a.w * a.h;
            };
            break;
        case 'max':
            func = function(a, b) {
                return Math.max(b.w, b.h) - Math.max(a.w, a.h);
            };
            break;
        case 'min':
            func = function(a, b) {
                return Math.min(b.w, b.h) - Math.min(a.w, a.h);
            };
            break;
    }
    return blocks.sort(func);
}

Parts = {
  init: function(blocks, canvasElement) {
    Parts.el = {
      canvas:   canvasElement,
      size:     $('#size'),
      sort:     $('#sort'),
      ratio:    $('#ratio'),
      nofit:    $('#nofit')
    };

    var desc = '';

    if (!Parts.el.canvas.getContext)
      return false;
    Parts.el.draw = Parts.el.canvas.getContext("2d");
//SVG('canvas').size(1200, 2400); 

    Parts.el.size.change(function() {
     Parts.run(blocks)
 });
    Parts.el.sort.change(function() {
     Parts.run(blocks)
 });

    return ( Parts.run(blocks));
   }, 

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  run: function(blocks) {
    var packer = Parts.packer();
    Parts.sort.now(blocks);
    packer.fit(blocks);
    Parts.canvas.reset(packer.root.w, packer.root.h);
    Parts.canvas.blocks(blocks);
    Parts.canvas.boundary(packer.root);
    return (Parts.report(blocks, packer.root.w, packer.root.h));
  },

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  packer: function() {
    var size = "1200x2400";
      var dims = size.split("x");
      return new Packer(parseInt(dims[0]), parseInt(dims[1]));
  },

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  report: function(blocks, w, h) {
    var fit = 0, nofit = [], block, n, len = blocks.length;
    for (n = 0 ; n < len ; n++) {
      block = blocks[n];
      if (block.fit)
 {
        fit = fit + block.area;
 }
      else
        nofit.push("" + block.w + "x" + block.h);
    }

    return "<br/><br/>Percentage of area utilized: " + (Math.round(100 * fit / (w * h))) + "%<br/>Total used area: " + fit + " mm<sup>2</sup><br/>Wastage area: " + ((w*h) - fit) + " mm<sup>2</sup><br/>";

    //Parts.el.nofit.html("Did not fit (" + nofit.length + ") :<br>" + nofit.join(", ")).toggle(nofit.length > 0);
  },

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  sort: {

    random  : function (a,b) { return Math.random() - 0.5; },
    w       : function (a,b) { return b.w - a.w; },
    h       : function (a,b) { return b.h - a.h; },
    a       : function (a,b) { return b.w*b.h - a.w*a.h; },
    max     : function (a,b) { return Math.max(b.w, b.h) - Math.max(a.w, a.h); },
    min     : function (a,b) { return Math.min(b.w, b.h) - Math.min(a.w, a.h); },

    height  : function (a,b) { return Parts.sort.msort(a, b, ['h', 'w']);               },
    width   : function (a,b) { return Parts.sort.msort(a, b, ['w', 'h']);               },
    area    : function (a,b) { return Parts.sort.msort(a, b, ['a', 'h', 'w']);          },
    maxside : function (a,b) { return Parts.sort.msort(a, b, ['max', 'min', 'h', 'w']); },

    msort: function(a, b, criteria) { /* sort by multiple criteria */
      var diff, n;
      for (n = 0 ; n < criteria.length ; n++) {
        diff = Parts.sort[criteria[n]](a,b);
        if (diff != 0)
          return diff;  
      }
      return 0;
    },

    now: function(blocks) {
      var sort = "area";
      if (sort != 'none')
        blocks.sort(Parts.sort[sort]);
    }
  },

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

canvas: {
  reset: function(width, height) {
   Parts.el.canvas.width = width + 1;
   Parts.el.canvas.height = height + 1;

   Parts.el.draw.clearRect(0, 0, Parts.el.canvas.width, Parts.el.canvas.height);


   var color1 = "#ffffff",
    color2 = "#d0d0d0";
   var numberOfStripes = width;
   for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStripes * 2; i++) {
    var thickness = 5;
    Parts.el.draw.beginPath();
    Parts.el.draw.strokeStyle = i % 2 ? color1 : color2;
    Parts.el.draw.lineWidth = thickness;
    Parts.el.draw.lineCap = 'round';
    Parts.el.draw.moveTo(i * thickness + thickness / 2 - Math.max(height,width), 0);
    Parts.el.draw.lineTo(0 + i * thickness + thickness / 2, Math.max(height,width));
    Parts.el.draw.stroke();
   }
   Parts.el.draw.lineWidth = 3;
   Parts.el.draw.strokeStyle = "#c0c0c0";
   Parts.el.draw.strokeRect(0 + 0.5, 0 + 0.5, width, height);
   //Parts.el.draw.fillStyle = "gray";
   //Parts.el.draw.fillRect(0 + 0.5, 0 + 0.5, width, height);
  },
  rect: function(x, y, w, h, color, id, name) {
   
   Parts.el.draw.fillStyle = "White";
   Parts.el.draw.fillRect(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, w, h);
   //Parts.el.draw.font= (w/10) + "px Comic Sans MS";
   Parts.el.draw.font = "12px Roboto";
   Parts.el.draw.fillStyle = "black";
   Parts.el.draw.textAlign = "center";
   //Parts.el.draw.fillText(id + "-" + name + " (" + w + "x" + h + ")", x+w/2, y+h/2);
   Parts.el.draw.fillText("#" + id + " " + name, x + w / 2, y + h / 2);
   Parts.el.draw.fillText(w + " mm", x + w / 2, y + h - 5);
   Parts.el.draw.save();
   Parts.el.draw.translate(x - w, y + h / 2);
   Parts.el.draw.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);
   Parts.el.draw.fillText(h + " mm", 0, 0 + w + 15);
   Parts.el.draw.restore();
  },

    stroke: function(x, y, w, h) {
      Parts.el.draw.strokeRect(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, w, h);
    },

    blocks: function(blocks) {
      var n, block;
      for (n = 0 ; n < blocks.length ; n++) {
        block = blocks[n];
        if (block.fit)
          Parts.canvas.rect(block.fit.x, block.fit.y, block.w, block.h, Parts.color(n), block.id, block.name);
      }
    },

    boundary: function(node) {
      if (node) {
        Parts.canvas.stroke(node.x, node.y, node.w, node.h);
        Parts.canvas.boundary(node.down);
        Parts.canvas.boundary(node.right);
      }
    }
  },

  colors: {
    pastel:         [ "#FFF7A5", "#FFA5E0", "#A5B3FF", "#BFFFA5", "#FFCBA5" ],
    basic:          [ "silver", "gray", "red", "maroon", "yellow", "olive", "lime", "green", "aqua", "teal", "blue", "navy", "fuchsia", "purple" ],
    gray:           [ "#111", "#222", "#333", "#444", "#555", "#666", "#777", "#888", "#999", "#AAA", "#BBB", "#CCC", "#DDD", "#EEE" ],
    vintage:        [ "#EFD279", "#95CBE9", "#024769", "#AFD775", "#2C5700", "#DE9D7F", "#7F9DDE", "#00572C", "#75D7AF", "#694702", "#E9CB95", "#79D2EF" ],
    solarized:      [ "#b58900", "#cb4b16", "#dc322f", "#d33682", "#6c71c4", "#268bd2", "#2aa198", "#859900" ],
    none:           [ "transparent" ]
  },

  color: function(n) {
    var cols = Parts.colors["none"];
    return cols[n % cols.length];
  }
}

function getConsumedPanels(blocks, panelWidth, panelHeight)
{
 var leftOver = 0;
 var count = 0;
 while (blocks.length > 0 && leftOver != blocks.length)
 {
  var leftOver = blocks.length;
  var r = [];
  toDelete = [];
  var bb=blocks;
  var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>',{'class':'canvas'});
  $("#canvas").append("<div><br/><br/>Panel:"+(count+1)+ " [material name] " + panelWidth + "x" + panelHeight + "<br/></div>");
  $("#canvas").append(newCanvas);

  $("#canvas").append(Parts.init(bb, $(".canvas")[count]))
    

  bb.forEach(function(o, i)
  {
   if (o.fit)
   {
    toDelete.push(i)
   }
   else; //document.write("Not fit");
  });
  for (var x = toDelete.length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
  {
   blocks.splice(toDelete[x], 1);
  }
  count++;
 }
 if (leftOver == blocks.length)
 {
  count = count + blocks.length;
 }
 return count;
}

var w = 100;
var d = 200;
var h = 300;
var t = 400;
var shelf_qty = 3;
var drawer_qty = 2;
var sheet_dim = {
 'w': 2400,
 'h': 1200
};


document.write(getConsumedPanels([{
                "w": 740,
                "h": 580,
                "area": 429200,
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Left Side Panel"
            }, {
                "w": 740,
                "h": 580,
                "area": 429200,
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Right Side Panel"
            }, {
                "w": 1200,
                "h": 580,
                "area": 696000,
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Bottom"
            }, {
                "w": 1200,
                "h": 100,
                "area": 120000,
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Top"
            }, {
                "w": 1200,
                "h": 100,
                "area": 120000,
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Top"
            }, {
                "w": 1200,
                "h": 740,
                "area": 888000,
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Back 1"
            }, {
                "w": 1200,
                "h": 370,
                "area": 444000,
                "id": 7,
                "name": "Back 2"
            }, {
                "w": 1200,
                "h": 580,
                "area": 696000,
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Shelf"
            }], sheet_dim.w, sheet_dim.h))
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The canvas code starts from canvas: class of the above code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read up on svg to know how it works? There are many tutorials available out there. Maybe try a simpler example first. This community is for helping with problems and answering questions not solving the task for you!